# Unified Android intent for geo check-ins

Tags: android, facebook, geolocation, android-intent, foursquare

I want to add a geo check-in (to Facebook places, Foursquare or Gowala) feature to my Android app and I am looking for an appropriate intent to do so.

Is there anything like that? If not, what is the best way to interact with the services mentioned above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For foursquare, you can send a user to the venue page of the foursquare app using an intent. There is no "universal" intent across all services though. See https://developer.foursquare.com/client/index for more details about foursquare android intents

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do so is checking each of one those's SDK for Android.

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

http://code.google.com/p/foursquare-android-sdk/

And dont know if there's any for gowala.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is one (yet), but have you considered getting in touch with the guys running [Open Intents](http://www.openintents.org/en/)? They run an intent registry for exactly these sorts of things.

Comment: I already checked out http://www.openintents.org/en/intentstable. Unfortunately there is no such intent.

Comment: no there isn't, I think the idea is you contribute back by adding one :-)